# calling a model function in the views in rails raising error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Here is the model

```
class Admin::Filter < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
    has_many :filter_values,class_name: "Admin::FilterValue",foreign_key: "admin_filter_id"
    enum field_type: [:select_tag,:select_tag_without_search,:check_box_tag]

    def underscore_filter_name
        if self.name.split.size > 1
            self.name.replace(self.name.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*/).join("_"))
        else
            "#{self.name.downcase}_filter"
        end
    end

end
```

The function I am talking about is `underscore_filter_name`. Now I am calling this inside the `rails console` like this: `Admin::Filter.first.underscore_filter_name` which returns a value but when I try similarly inside the view it throws an error. Here is the view:

```
-@filters.each do |filter|
      %legend
        =filter.name
        -case filter.field_type
        -when "select_tag"
          = simple_form_for :"#{filter.underscore_field_name(filter)}",:url=> admin_requests_path,:method => "get",html: {:"data-filter"=>"#{filter.underscore_field_name}"}  do |f|
            = f.select("#{filter.name}", filter.filter_values.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => "Please select a #{filter.name}"},{:multiple => true,class: "form-control chosen-select select_tag_filter"})
        -when "select_tag_without_search"
          = select_tag "#{filter.name}", options_for_select(filter.filter_values.all.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id]}), { :multiple => true,class: "search-free-chosen-select"}
        -when "check_box_tag"
          = simple_form_for :priority,:url=> admin_requests_path,:method => "get",html: {id: "priority_filter"}  do |f|
            = f.collection_check_boxes "#{filter.name}", filter.filter_values,:id,:name, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'
```

The below line is the error I am getting:

```
undefined method `underscore_field_name' for #<Admin::Filter:0x007f07a322f068>
```

Why is this? I am using Rails 4.1

Comment: Name of method in model is different from that used in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined **`underscore_filter_name`** as the method name and you have typed in the view as **`underscore_field_name`**. So is the error.

Change it to

```
= simple_form_for :"#{filter.underscore_filter_name(filter)}",:url=> admin_requests_path,:method => "get",html: {:"data-filter"=>"#{filter.underscore_field_name}"}  do |f|
```

This should resolve the error.

Comment: @Aravind Don't be,mistakes happen :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got in the view...

```
underscore_field_name
```

but the name of the method is

```
underscore_filter_name
```